# SQL JOIN without excess info

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've spent about an hour and a half trying to work this out, and I'm sure its because its not the best function to use, but I need to for my assessment.

The idea is I have 3 tables, and want to return all the information for each 'guestName' along with its related 'hotelName', 'roomNo' and 'dateTo' cells. I can't work out how to make this work with a simple Join.

```
SELECT guestName, hotelName, roomNo, dateTo 
FROM guest 
JOIN hotel, booking 
ORDER BY guestName
```

This is just returning every entry from all the tables I have joined with, repeating guest names and hotel names to fit the room number and date to columns.

[JOIN error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUloj.png)

Each SELECT item has its own table, except 'roomNo' which is within the booking table. All my searching just tells me to use other methods of JOIN, which I'm sure works better,  but those are coming up in later assessment pieces so I need to use standard JOIN.

Cheers for any direction on this.

Comment: Do your tables have primary key?

Comment: Your JOIN clause does not look right. I don't have MySQL here, but I believe it should be something like `SELECT guestName, hotelName, roomNo, dateTo FROM guest g INNER JOIN hotel h ON h.id = guest.hotel_id INNER JOIN booking b ON b.id = h.id_booking`. I don't know your data model, but would definitely go for something like this. It must be returning every entry because there's no restriction on your JOIN. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ON` statement to specify JOIN condition

```
SELECT guestName, hotelName, roomNo, dateTo 
FROM guest g
JOIN booking b ON b.bookingId = g.bookingId
JOIN hotel h ON b.hotelId = h.hotelId 
ORDER BY g.guestName
```